# Pass an option value variable (JavaScript) to PHP query. Joomla website

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I have been struggling with my script for sometime now.

I need to find a way to pass/send my option value variable `$varState` (from dropdownbox) to MySQL query. I have tried ajax  but I can't seem to get it working.

You can find example on my [development site](http://model-engineering.nl/acceptatie/verkooppunten.html) and my code is the following:

```
<form name="klassiek" >
<select name="landen"  onChange="updateprovincie(this.selectedIndex)"  style="width: 250px"  >
<option value="">kies land</option>
<option value="NL">Nederland</option>
<option value="BE">Belgie</option>
<option value="ts">test</option>
</select>

<br />
<select name="provincie" id="provincie" action="/acceptatie/verkooppunten.html"  method="post"  size="4" style="width: 250px" onClick=" myVariable()" >
</select>

</form>
<br>

</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

var landenlist=document.klassiek.landen
var provincielist=document.klassiek.provincie

var provincie=new Array()
provincie[0]=""
provincie[1]=["Drenthe|drenthe", "Flevoland|flevoland", "Friesland|friesland", "Gelderland|gelderland", "Groningen|groningen", "Gelderland|gelderland", "Limburg|limburg","Noord Brabant|noordbrabant", "Noord Holland|noord holland", "Overijssel|overijssel", "Utrecht|utrecht", "Zeeland|zeeland", "Zuid Holland|zuidholland"]
provincie[2]=["Antwerpen|antwerpenvalue", "Limburg|limburgvalue", "Oost Vlaanderen|oostvlaanderenvalue", "Vlaams Brabant|vlaamsbrabantvalue", "West Vlaanderen|westvlaanderenvalue", "Waals Brabant|waalsbrabantvalue","Henegouwen|hennegouwenvalue","Luik|Luikvalue", "Luxemburg|Luxemburgalue","Namen|namenvalue"] 

function myVariable(){
var state=document.getElementById('provincie').value;
//get value and pass to php script
document.write(state);//need to pass this value to php query
}

function updateprovincie(selectedprovinciegroup)
{
provincielist.options.length=0
  if (selectedprovinciegroup>0)
  { 
  for (i=0; i<provincie[selectedprovinciegroup].length; i++)
  provincielist.options[provincielist.options.length]=new Option(provincie[selectedprovinciegroup][i].split("|")[0], provincie[selectedprovinciegroup][i].split("|")[1],provincie[selectedprovinciegroup][i].split("|")[2])
  }
}

</script>


<br /><br />
<?php
$varState= $_POST["provincie"];
//print_r($varState);


$query3="SELECT * FROM jos_contact_details WHERE catid=80 && state = '$varState'" ;
$result=mysql_query($query3);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Naam</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Adres</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Postcode</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Land</font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Productgroep</font></td>
</tr>

<?php

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"address");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"state");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"country");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"productgroep");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
</tr>


<?php
$i++;
}

mysql_close();
//einde  code
```

I hope someone can help.

```
//ajaxcode in function myVariable()

function myVariable(str){ var
> state=document.getElementById('provincie').value; //get value and pass
> to php script //document.write(state);
> 
> 
> if (str=="")   {   document.getElementById("provincie").innerHTML=""; 
> return;   }  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {// code for IE7+, Firefox,
> Chrome, Opera, Safari   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();   } else   {//
> code for IE6, IE5   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
> } xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()   {   if
> (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
>     {
>     document.getElementById("provincie").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
>     }   } xmlhttp.open("GET","/acceptatie/verkooppunten.html?varState="+str,true);
> xmlhttp.send(); }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick look it appears that your PHP script is looking for `$varState= $_POST["provincie"]` while your AJAX is sending `"GET","/acceptatie/verkooppunten.html?varState="+str`.

Change your PHP to look for `$_GET['varState']` and it should work.

Comment: it didn't help.   <?php

$varState=$_GET['varState']; 



$query3="SELECT * FROM jos_contact_details WHERE catid=80 && state = '".$varState."'" ;
$result=mysql_query($query3);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
?>

Comment: console shows a "uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined " pfff . So my variable is not being seen.